# anonymous extension of an existing type in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm writing some types of structures of an existing API.

```
export interface Filter {
 value: number;
 operator: string;
};

export interface MySetup {
  foo: Filter;
  bar: {
   value: number;
   operator: string;
   additionWithName: string;
  };
  alice: {
   value: number;
   operator: string;
   additionWithOtherName: string;
  };
}
```

I can write this also like:

```
export interface Filter {
 value: number;
 operator: string;
};
export interface FilterBar extends Filter {
  additionWithName: string;
};
export interface FilterAlice extends Filter {
  additionWithOtherName: string;
};

export interface MySetup {
  foo: Filter;
  bar: FilterBar;
  alice: FilterAlice;
}
```

Is it possible to extend some interfaces in an anonymous way? I want to write something like:

```
export interface Filter {
 value: number;
 operator: string;
};

export interface MySetup {
  foo: Filter;
  bar: Filter extends {additionWithOtherName: string;};
  alice: Filter extends {additionWithName: string;};
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do inline extends, but an [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) will provide a good approximation of this, ie. a type that must have the properties of the interface and some other extra properties:

```
export interface Filter {
 value: number;
 operator: string;
};

export interface MySetup {
  foo: Filter;
  bar: Filter & {additionWithOtherName: string;};
  alice: Filter & {additionWithName: string;};
}
```

Comment: [Intersection Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)